# Pandas: Matching two dataframes with different index

Tags: python, pandas

Consider two dataframes:

```
>>> X = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,12).reshape(4,3),columns=['a','b','c'])
>>> X
   a   b   c
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11
>>> 
>>> Y = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['abc',22],['fgh',44],['ijk',0],['xee',99],['RGD',3]]),columns = ['x','y'])
>>> Y
     x   y
0  abc  22
1  fgh  44
2  ijk   0
3  xee  99
4  RGD   3
```

I want to join these two dataframes in a way such that I get the result

```
   a   b   c
0  ijk 1  2
1  RGD 4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11
```

I have tried the following:

```
    >>> X.loc[X['a'].astype(str).isin(Y['y']),'a']=Y[Y['y'].astype(str).isin(X['a'])]
>>> X
     a   b   c
0  nan   1   2
1  nan   4   5
2 6.00   7   8
3 9.00  10  11
```

I think it is trying to match them index by index, giving me a nan. I have tried joining X and Y also but can't get that to work. I think merging the two dataframes would work but I don't know how to merge them on column 'a' and 'y' appropriately

Any tips here would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` to replace `a` in `X` with `x` in `Y` if it exists otherwise keep the original values:

```
X['a'] = X.a.astype(str).map(Y.set_index('y').x).fillna(X.a)
```

[image]

---

Another option with merge, (I corrected the data type in `Y` i.e. assume if the y column is float instead of string):

```
X = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,12).reshape(4,3),columns=['a','b','c'])
Y = pd.DataFrame([['abc',22],['fgh',44],['ijk',0],['xee',99],['RGD',3]],columns = ['x','y'])
```

Then a merge on `x` and `a` columns gives:

```
mX = X.merge(Y.set_index("y"), left_on="a", right_index=True, how="left")
mX
```

[image]

Then depends on your need, you can combine the columns `a` and `x` together or leave them as is which I think is actually more reasonable:

To combine column a and x, you can just do:

```
mX.assign(a = mX.x.fillna(mX.a)).drop('x', axis=1)
```

This gives the same result as the first option.

Comment: Thanks - seems to work well. Do you have any idea how to this with with .merge()?

Comment: Brilliant thanks again. Could I ask why using set_index("y") is necessary for both of the solutions?

Comment: It's just a trick to save the effort to drop it later on, as you will have duplicated merge_on(key) columns in the result.

Comment: Ah OK that makes sense - and for the first solution it seems completely necessary? It seems as though it "matches" based off the index

Comment: Right. For the map method it's necessary, as map looks for the index value pairs for matching.

Comment: Thanks again, funnily enough it seems to not be working with the merge method. The only way I can get it to work is if I set X = X.astype(str)